# Detect mention in discordgo

Tags: go, discord, discordgo

I would like my discord bot to detect mentions from command and I can't really do that, even though I could send message with mention from my bot.
Could you help me out here?

By the way I am using discordgo and it is written in golang

```
func messageHandler(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.MessageCreate) {
     //instead of " " it should be what will detect mention
     if m.Content == prefix+commands["warning"]+" " {
             fmt.Print("do somethin")
             s.ChannelMessageSend(m.ChannelID, "<@348571774960533508>")
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that once you know that the command syntax is correct, split the message content into an array, and then use the following Regular Expression to parse the validate the mention in the expected position:

```
const (
    //MinimumCharactersOnID ...
    MinimumCharactersOnID int = 16
)

var ( 
    //RegexUserPatternID ...
    RegexUserPatternID *regexp.Regexp = regexp.MustCompile(fmt.Sprintf(`^(<@!(\d{%d,})>)$`, MinimumCharactersOnID))
)
```

So it would look something like this

```
func messageHandler(s *discordgo.Session, m *discordgo.MessageCreate) {
     if !strings.HasPrefix(m.Content, prefix+commands["warning"]) {
         return //Doesn't have the command syntax prefix
     }

     parameters := strings.Split(m.Content, " ")
     if RegexUserPatternID.MatchString(parameters[1]){ //Assumming that the expected position of the mention in your command is in the #2
         //Here you have validated that there's a mention in the command
     } 

}
```